# ray can't find obviously intersections

Tags: three.js, raycasting

A cube is in the scene. I put a small sphere-geometry `objects[i]` on the front face. Rotating the cube in a position which hides the front-face. The sphere-geometry is hidden yet too. now I set a ray from the camera to the sphere-geometry but no cube-faces and no sphere-geometry getting intersected. why?

the vectors of the ray origin (camera) and ray direction (objects[i].position) in the console are correctly.

```
function detectIntersections () {

var detectDirection = new THREE.Vector3();
detectDirection.x = objects[i].position.x;
detectDirection.y = objects[i].position.y;
detectDirection.z = objects[i].position.z;

var detectOrigin = new THREE.Vector3(camera.position.x,camera.position.y,camera.position.z);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.set(detectOrigin, detectDirection);

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true )};
```

I expect a non empty intersects-Array.

Comment: It appears you are using the incorrect `detectDirection`. The direction is in relation to the camera's position, not the position of the object in world space. If you want to cast towards the direction the camera is facing, you can simply use `camera.getWorldDirection()`.

Comment: can you explain please. I want the ray from my point of view through the sphere-geometry. it's like raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera) but instead of mouse Vector2 it's a Vector3.

Comment: Have you made sure that `objects[i]` exists? And is it part of scene.children?

Comment: Yes. console said: Mesh { [...] type: "Mesh", parent: Scene, …}

Comment: Direction must be normalized: `var detectDirection = new THREE.Vector3(); detectDirection.copy(objects[i].position).sub(camera.position).normalize();`

Comment: It works with your modification @prisoner849. Thank you.

Comment: @stewahn You're welcome :) When you get a copy of the object's position as the direction, it means you get it from the world center, whereas you have to get it from the camera, that's why there is `.sub(camera.position)`.

Comment: @prisoner849 I don't understand the coordinate systems in 3d graphics yet and I not ask for details. You solve my situation and furthermore you give me a helpful direction. Thank you very much.